# Rename Folder in ItemUpdating

Tags: event-handlers, item-updating

I just wanted to rename an item of a custom content type based on the default folder content type while it is being created.
My idea was to do it in ItemUpdating event due to other operations I am doing. But the result is that everything works find but not the renaming of the folder by changing the FileLeafRef nor the Name field.

```
properties.AfterProperties["FileLeafRef"] = "NewFolderName";
```

In ItemUpdated everything works fine :( 
Is it impossible to do it in ItemUpdating or am I doing anything wrong? If it is impossible, it would be nice of you to help me understanding the reason for that.

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: did you debug or receive any error in uls log?

Comment: I did not receive any error. It just runs through. The only results are, that the Document Name will not be renamed. (FileLeafRef is being ignored) and another field where a TaxonomyFieldValueCollection is in is ignored as well. Simple text/string fields are correctly modified.